# How I can add summary to this Facebook Request?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting photo likes with this request, but I want to add the summary which returns to me the total likes count:

```
 NSString *path=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/likes",IdPhoto];
  [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:path
                                 parameters:nil
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error)
     {
         
         
     }];
```

How can I add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this call:

```
"/%@/likes?summary=true"
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/likes#read